# For hosting resellers, what's a good F/OSS ticketing system?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, open-source, ticket-system

Been thinking about starting a hosting company through a reseller plan. What's a good F/OSS ticketing system that:

- securely separates my potential customers (can't have them seeing each other's tickets, even if they guess ticket numbers)
- provides interacting with POP/SMTP so that people can email in a request
- is fairly intuitive
- is PHP-based

Anyone know from personal experience what they think is the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hesk](http://www.hesk.com/) isn't open source but it is free. It does all of the above except allow the emailing of a request. I've used it and it is very intuitive to use.

Comment: Perfect. I'll use it. Although it doesn't use an MVC framework or page templates in its code, which is a bummer -- it still only uses just a few files, so I think I can customize it. Besides, it's so well-made from a user-intuitive perspective that I doubt I may need to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

We used to use Hesk and still have a licence for it allowing us to remove the "Powered by" in the templates but have now moved to [WHMCS](http://www.whmcs.com/) which integrates our billing, ticket system, sales, invoices, account creation, domain registration etc etc. A one stop solution and we don't need to look any further.